# Laravel 5.4 get only 2 column data from db as array key and value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.4

[db column screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J42P4.png)

I want to fetch only two columns data from table 1st column data as array key and another column data as array value.

as array['wid'=>'temp']

result should be  array['1'=>'1.5','2'=>'11.50']

for laravel 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
$data = DB::table('city_list')->select('cid','city_name')->get(); 
$val = array();

foreach ($data as $key => $value) { 
    $val[$value->cid]=$value->city_name; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#retrieving-results) method (scroll down to the **Retrieving A List Of Column Values**) e.g.

```
$data = DB::table('city_list')->pluck('city_name', 'cid');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Collection **pluck()** The pluck method retrieves all of the values for a given key:

```
$data = DB::table('city_list')->pluck('city_name','cid');
```

For more information visit laravel [doc here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck)